# Remove duplicates and show recent dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have data on an excel worksheet in column A cells(23,i) and A celles(24,i) ordered like this
[image]d like this

I want to show the data in a listbox without duplicates and showing only recent dates for each value (N IT) like this: 
[image]

To show the list I created a button, and set this code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  If Me.ListBox_Pers.ListIndex = -1 Then
       MsgBox ("Vous n'avez pas selectionner une personne")
  Else

      Acrtu_IT
      Load UF_Profil_Edit1
      UF_Profil_Edit1.Show
     'UF_Choix_Pers_Edit.ListBox_Pers.Clear

  End If
End Sub
```

Where:
    `Private Sub Actu_IT()`

```
Personne = UF_Profil_Edit1.TextBox_Nom & " " & UF_Profil_Edit1.TextBox_Prenom.Value
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Personne)
UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.Clear
Fin_Col_IT = ws.Cells(23, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column
UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.ColumnCount = 4
UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.ColumnWidths = "50;450;60;20"

Set Plage = ws.Rows(23)
Set Plage2 = ws_Liste_IT.Columns(2)
For i = 2 To Fin_Col_IT
   Val_Cherch = ws.Cells(23, i).Value
   Set Trouve = Plage.Cells.Find(what:=Val(Val_Cherch))
   If Trouve Is Nothing Then
   Else

      Set Trouve2 = Plage2.Cells.Find(what:=Val(Val_Cherch))
      If Trouve2 Is Nothing Then
      Else

         UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.AddItem Trouve2.Offset(, 2)
         '---------------Nom de l'IT------------------------------
         UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.List(UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.ListCount - 1, 1) = Trouve2.Offset(, 1)
         '---------------Date de fin de la formation------------------------------
        UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.List(UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.ListCount - 1, 2) = ws.Cells(24, Trouve.Column)
 '---------------n° IT---------------------
        UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.List(UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.ListCount - 1, 3) = Trouve2
       '-----------°DE-------------------

     End If
  End If
Next i

'---sorting data in alphabetic order-----------------
    Dim a()
    a = UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.List
If UBound(a, 1) > 1 Then
    Module2.Tri a(), LBound(a), UBound(a), 0
    UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT.List = a
Else
End If
```

How can show only recent dates for each value in celle A(23,i), Thank you

Comment: How do you define "recent dates"?

Comment: @FaneDuru as u can see in the 1st picture I have  the item "1" appears twice on the 1st line when i want to display my list on the 2nd picture I want the item 1 with the recent date 01/03/2020 to appear and  not 13/04/2019, same thong for the others. For 2 i want 6/03/2019 to appear and  not older dates. Thank u

Comment: It is difficult to understand too much from what you presented in your question. What does `Truve2` should be? How does the `ws_Liste_IT.Columns(2)` look? Only that enumeration `1 to n`? At the first glance `ws.Cells(24, Trouve.Column)` should be transformed in something to look for `Max` in the date range. And I would suggest to firstly input all these data in an array, check the maximum date for what you already loaded and replace the date the new one is more recent, then drop the array in the list box `List`... I cannot build something to test with the information you provide...

Comment: Or, simpler, load the list box as you do and work only on the loaded list box and remove the not necessary lines...

Comment: Can the `IT maitrises` be  more then two in the list box?

Comment: _"I want to show the data in a listbox without duplicates"_. Did you mean that you want the listbox item are all unique value ? (in 2nd image on your post, the listbox item has a duplicate value). You wrote : _"showing only recent dates for each value"_, did you mean "recent dateS" is the "highest" date (without S). For example in the first image on your post, the "highest" date is March 1 2020. So, your 2nd image listbox will be something like this.. Nom:AAA Date:highest date from the data, Nom:BBB Date:highest date from the data, NOM:CCC... and so on. So the item of NOM always unique.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the next function, to process your list box as (I understood) you need:

```
Private Function arrangeListBox(lst As MSForms.ListBox)
 Dim i As Long, refDate As Date, j As Long
Beginning:
 For i = 0 To lst.ListCount - 1
    refDate = DateValue(lst.list(i, 2))
    For j = 0 To lst.ListCount - 1
        If lst.list(i, 0) = lst.list(j, 0) And _
            DateValue(lst.list(j, 2)) < refDate Then
            lst.RemoveItem (j): GoTo Beginning
        End If
    Next j
 Next i
End Function
```

The function must be called at the end of your code as:

```
arrangeListBox UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_IT
```

Please, confirm that it does what you need. If you would like to load the list box only with the appropriate lines (respecting the rule of most recent date) you must provide both sheets involved in processing (with relevant data, to make them able to be understood)...

Comment: @FaruSZ: Did you test the above code? Does it what you need?